# How to define test task that is limited to package?

Tags: testing, gradle, groovy, package, task

I have gradle project with tests. Tests are grouped into two packages. I would like to have test task for each package.

My project in gradle:

```
project(":tests:my-project") {

    ext {
        drivers = ["phantomJs", "chrome"]
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }

    apply plugin: "groovy"
    apply from: "gradle/osSpecificDownloads.gradle"

    List suites = ['smoke', 'stress']
    Map testPackages = ['smoke': 'packagename1.*', 'stress': 'packagename2.*']


    drivers.each { driver ->
            task "${driver}Test"(type: Test) {
                reports {
                    html.destination = reporting.file("$name/tests")
                    junitXml.destination = file("$buildDir/test-results/$name")
                }

                outputs.upToDateWhen { false }  

                systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("$name/geb")
                systemProperty "geb.env", driver

            }
    }

    chromeTest {
        dependsOn unzipChromeDriver
        def chromedriverFilename = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? "chromedriver.exe" : "chromedriver"        systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", new File(unzipChromeDriver.outputs.files.singleFile, chromedriverFilename).absolutePath
    }

    phantomJsTest {
            dependsOn unzipPhantomJs
            def phantomJsFilename = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? "bin/phantomjs.exe" : "bin/phantomjs"
            systemProperty "phantomjs.binary.path", new File(unzipPhantomJs.outputs.files.singleFile, phantomJsFilename).absolutePath
    }

    test {
        dependsOn drivers.collect { tasks["${it}Test"] }
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do it this way:

First, create 2 tasks, one for smoke tests and one for stress tests. For example, I'll show you only one - smoke tests. Stress tests task will look the same.

```
//this task will run all the smoke tests
task runSmokeTests() {

}
```

Then change your `testPackages` values, in order the could be used by Gradle:

```
Map testPackages = ['smoke': 'packagename1/*', 'stress': 'packagename2/*']
```

Then iterate over drivers and create task of `Test` type, the same as you did, but with `include` parameter pointing to the package with the smoke tests, after task definition make the `runSmokeTests` task depending on this newly created task, like so:

```
drivers.each { driver ->
    Task smokeTestTask = task "${driver}SmokeTest"(type: Test) {
        reports {
            html.destination = reporting.file("$name/tests")
            junitXml.destination = file("$buildDir/test-results/$name")
        }

        include testPackages.get('smoke')

        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

        systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("$name/geb")
        systemProperty "geb.env", driver

    }
    runSmokeTests.dependsOn smokeTestTask 
}
```

Since now, you have created at least 2 task: `phantomJsSmokeTest` and `chromeSmokeTest`, each include only it's own package. Since `runSmokeTests` depends on both of them, you can run it, to run all the smoke tests.

If you wish, you can add one more iteration within `drivers.each` to iterate over test types and provide some more logic to make your configuration even more flexible. But, IMHO, that's no good, because this solution could become be hard to maintain and understand and I don't think, you will have a large amount of test types.